# What is wkbType -2147483646 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, well-known-binary

I want to find out the wkbType of a layer, this is my code:

`print layer.wkbType()`

Usually when it is a line geometry layer, it would give me 2. But instead it is giving me -2147483646.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2.5D types has such values:

```
wkbPoint25D = -2147483647,   /* 2.5D extensions as per 99-402 */
wkbLineString25D = -2147483646,
wkbPolygon25D = -2147483645,
wkbMultiPoint25D = -2147483644,
wkbMultiLineString25D = -2147483643,
wkbMultiPolygon25D = -2147483642,
wkbGeometryCollection25D = -2147483641
```

To strip 2.5D from geometry you can use:

```
ogr.GT_Flatten(layer.wkbType())
```

To get geometry name:

```
ogr.GeometryTypeToName(layer.wkbType())
```

And full python example:

```
>>> from osgeo import ogr
>>> ogr.GT_Flatten(-2147483646)
2
>>> ogr.GeometryTypeToName(-2147483646)
'3D Line String'
```

Comment: Or `QgsWkbTypes.flatType` to stay within one library.