# GDAL/OGR python: geometryType change for linear ring?

Tags: python, gdal, polygon, ogr

I found something unexpected when trying to create a simple polygon, following the "cookbook" example in:

https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html

```
from osgeo import ogr

ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
print(ring.GetGeometryType())
ring.AddPoint(1179091.1646903288, 712782.8838459781)
ring.AddPoint(1161053.0218226474, 667456.2684348812)
ring.AddPoint(1214704.933941905, 641092.8288590391)
ring.AddPoint(1228580.428455506, 682719.3123998424)
ring.AddPoint(1218405.0658121984, 721108.1805541387)
ring.AddPoint(1179091.1646903288, 712782.8838459781)
print(ring.GetGeometryType())

# Create polygon
poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly.AddGeometry(ring)
print(poly)
print(poly.GetGeometryType())
```

This gives as output:

```
2
-2147483646
POLYGON ((1179091.16469033 712782.883845978 0,1161053.02182265 667456.268434881 0,1214704.9339419 641092.828859039 0,1228580.42845551 682719.312399842 0,1218405.0658122 721108.180554139 0,1179091.16469033 712782.883845978 0))
-2147483645
```

i.e. the geometryType changes from 2 to some weird negative integer after creation, and similarly for the resulting polygon.

This matters, because later on, I want to check geometryType and the polygon is obviously no longer of type ogr.wkbPolygon (3)

As a workaround I check for GetGeometryName() instead, but this is definitely odd.

Guido Lemoine

NB. Python 3.6.9 with the latest GDAL source build (3.1.0) but also different older versions.

Comment: Does this answer your problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245936/gdal-ogr-geometry-type-python?

Comment: No it doesn't. I know you can use GetGeometryName as an alternative, but that still doesn't explain why GetGeometryType returns an inconsistent result that propagates to a derived geometry.

Comment: Actually the negative numbers mean 25D geometries https://gist.github.com/walkermatt/7121427. I do not know what changed them from 2D into 25D. But hey, see https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr-pysrc.html#Geometry.GetGeometryType: Fetch geometry type. 
Note that the geometry type may include the 2.5D flag. To get a 2D 
flattened version of the geometry type apply the wkbFlatten() macro to 
the return result.

Comment: A new trial: Does this answer your question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253243/what-is-wkbtype-2147483646-in-qgis?

Comment: Ok, AddPoint is xyz and AddPoint_2D is for xy only https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr-pysrc.html.

Comment: @user30184 You should put your comments as answer. AddPoint 
"upgraded" the geometry type to 2.5D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OGR geometry type codes of 25D geometries are small negative numbers https://gist.github.com/walkermatt/7121427

```
-2147483647 Point25D
-2147483646 LineString25D
-2147483645 Polygon25D
-2147483644 MultiPoint25D
-2147483643 MultiLineString25D
-2147483642 MultiPolygon25D
          0 Geometry
          1 Point
          2 Line
          3 Polygon
          4 MultiPoint
          5 MultiLineString
          6 MultiPolygon
        100 No Geometry
```

Function AddPoint adds a point with x, y, and z coordinates https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr-pysrc.html

```
 def AddPoint(self, *args, **kwargs): 
 """AddPoint(Geometry self, double x, double y, double z=0)""" 
 return _ogr.Geometry_AddPoint(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

There is another function AddPoint_2D that is using only x and y.

```
def AddPoint_2D(self, *args): 
"""AddPoint_2D(Geometry self, double x, double y)""" 
return _ogr.Geometry_AddPoint_2D(self, *args)
```

You have two alternatives for getting answer "2" in your first example.

1. Build the geometry as you did but ask the geometry type as flattened into 2D

   ```
   print(ogr.GT_Flatten(ring.GetGeometryType()))
   2
   ```
2. Build the geometry as 2D from the beginning

   ```
   from osgeo import ogr

   ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
   print(ring.GetGeometryType())
   ring.AddPoint_2D(1179091.1646903288, 712782.8838459781)
   ring.AddPoint_2D(1161053.0218226474, 667456.2684348812)
   ring.AddPoint_2D(1214704.933941905, 641092.8288590391)
   ring.AddPoint_2D(1228580.428455506, 682719.3123998424)
   ring.AddPoint_2D(1218405.0658121984, 721108.1805541387)
   ring.AddPoint_2D(1179091.1646903288, 712782.8838459781)
   print(ring.GetGeometryType())
   2
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the 25D geometries. Trouble is that GetGeometryName does not mention the 25D part, otherwise it would have given some clue about this.